# Database recommendation

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, monetdb, database

I have a collection of data that looks as follows:

```
id   name     c1    c2    c3    c4   ...  c50
-----------------------------------------------
1    string1  0.1   0.32  0.54 -1.2  ...  2.3
2    string2  0.12  0.12 -0.34  2.45 ...  1.3
...
(millions of records)
```

So I have an id column, a string column, then 50 floating point columns.

There will be only one type of query run on this data that in a traditional SQL SELECT statement would look like this:

`SELECT name FROM table WHERE ((a1-c1)+(a2-c2)+(a3-c3)+...+(a50-c50)) > 1;` where `a1,a2,a3,etc` are values that are generated before the query is sent (not housed in the data table).

My question is this: **Does anyone have any recommendations as to what type of database would handle this type of query the fastest.**  I have used `SQL server` (which is majorly slow), so I am looking for other opinions.

Would there be a way to optimize SQL server for this type of query? I have also been curious about column store databases such as `MonetDB`. Or perhaps a document store database such as `MongoDB`. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: Where do those a-columns come from?

Comment: @Mark, Thanks, I just forgot the equality. I corrected the question ;)

Comment: @sjngm, the 'a' data is generated client side before the SELECT statement is sent. So for all practical purposes, they are constants.

Comment: @Brett: I *really* hope you didn't actually mean equality. Looking at your update it seems you didn't, fortunately.

Comment: @Mark, ok, good point. I hadn't thought of it that way. The 'a' values are generated client side, and are different for each query.

Comment: You can probably simplify the computation that you are performing on each row. Notice that your equation is (a1 - c1) + (a2 - c2) + ... + (a50 - c50) = (a1 + a2 + ... + a50) - (c1 + c2 + ... + c50 ). Thus, in your DB you just need one field that holds the total of the columns and in your client just send the total of your a's. and now you query would just need WHERE (atotal - ctotal) > 1.

Comment: @Brett: What you are doing does not look like a dot product to me. The method that Waleed Al-Balooshi suggested (and that I also have suggested in my updated answer) won't work for a dot product but it will work for the query you posted. Which is it?

Comment: Brett as Mark explains this is NOT a dot product. a dot product would be a1c1 + a2c2 + ... + a50c50.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can continue using SQL Server and use a [persisted computed column](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1682) that calculates the sum of all the values and index that.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD SumOfAllColumns AS (c1 + c2 + ... + c50) PERSISTED
```

Then you can rearrange your query as:

```
SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE SumOfAllColumns < a1+a2+a3+...+a50 - 1
```

This query will be able to use the index on the computed column and should find the relevant rows quickly.

Comment: +1 For link recycling :P

Comment: +1 I would recommend as I did in my comment in the main question that the total of a's just be sent rather than 50 individual variables. Assuming that he is using a Stored Procedure

Comment: I like this approach (Thanks to Waleed too). Quick question about the PERSISTED column though. It looks to me like this is the same thing as pre-calculating the sum and just adding this data when the data is inserted. I suppose the PERSISTED column allows me to modify the 'c' data post-insert though???

Comment: @Brett: Yes, the column will be kept in sync with the data automatically. If you update one of the values then the value in the persisted column will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

To stick with SQL Server:

If you always include the same calculations in your queries (same field + or - the same other field, etc) you can create [computed columns with persisted values.](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1682)

Currently your queries will be slow because the engine is running a complicated mathematical operation for each row.

If you add a column with the results, the math is all done once and then it will be a lot faster to run queries.

Comment: +1 here too. :) But now I have my doubts as to whether our answers are correct. See the comments to the question.

Comment: @Mark Byers - If he runs multiple queries for the same set of "constants" then it will still be a monumental improvement.

Answer (score 0):

An in memory database would be best.   Have a look at http://hsqldb.org/

Depending on how many millions of rows you have...

Answer (score 0):

Your query condition can be rewritten as:

```
(a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + a50) > 1 + (c1 + c2 + c3 + ... + c50)
```

You can precompute `c = 1 + c1 + ... + c50` on the database side and `a = a1 + ... + a50` on the client side.  Then the query then reduces to `... WHERE @a > c`.  This opens an opportunity to use an index.

However, floating point numbers do not index well in most databases (including SQL Server).  If we can make some assumptions about the data, we might be able to work around this.  For example, if the numbers are only stored to two digits of precision as in the example, then we can multiply all the numbers by 100 to obtain integers.  Then, indexing will work well.  Reasonably well, that is... it depends on how many rows meet the condition.  Half of "millions of rows" is still a lot of rows.

Even if the values have truly variable precision, so two digits are not accurate enough, it might still make sense to create the integer index to reduce the rows that need to be checked.  The query can check both the approximate value (to hit the index) and the exact value (to get the precise result).  If you do that, make sure that the original values are rounded in the right direction to avoid losing precise results.